# AI for depth-first walking in a maze, with variable depth look ahead search for dead ends and finish point

Tags: c++, ai, pathfinding, depth-first-search

This code is a part of a little game I've started a week ago.
It is too extensive to review at once, so I'm picking the most interesting and crucial parts.
Start with the AI.

It has public update function that gets called from the player model's evolve function and calls it's public setDirection function.

Following are the h and cpp files:

```
#pragma once
#include "MazePlayerControllerInterface.h"
#include "CMaze.h"
#include <stack>
#include <set>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <memory>


namespace amazeinggame
{

    class CMazePlayerModel;
    class CMazeGameWorldModel;
    //we all know the AI could beat the player hands down
    //if I so chose (using a non-greedy algorithm like dijkstra) - but that would make the game less fun to play...
    //So this is a dumbed down AI, to give the human player a sense of value.
    class CMazePlayerAIController :
        public CMazePlayerControllerInterface
    {
    public:
        CMazePlayerAIController(const CMazeGameWorldModel & in_worldModel);
        virtual ~CMazePlayerAIController();
        void update(CMazePlayerModel * const in_playerModel) final;
        //determines how far ahead the AI can look from where it is now. 
        //The default is 3
        void setAILevel(int in_level);
    private:
        maze::Direction getNextDirection(int x, int y, maze::Direction direction);
        bool getPossibleTurns(std::array<maze::Direction, 4> &out_possibleTurns, int & out_numOfPossibleTurns, 
            int & out_preferedDirectionIdx, maze::Direction & out_backDirectoin ,
            int x, int y, maze::Direction in_direction, int depth = 1);
        const CMazeGameWorldModel * _worldModel = nullptr;
        int _prevX = -1, _prevY = -1;
        maze::Direction _prevDirection = maze::Direction::NotSet;
        enum class AIWalkState { Explore, Rollback } _currentWalkState = AIWalkState::Explore;
        int _lookAheadDepth = 3; //how far can the AI look ahead to see if a direction is a viable one.
        std::default_random_engine randomEngine;
        std::array<int, 4> _possibleTurnIdx;
        std::pair<int, int> _finishPoint;
        bool isAlreadyWalking = false;
        struct SJunction
        {
            SJunction(int in_x, int in_y, maze::Direction in_direction, std::shared_ptr<SJunction> in_parent = nullptr)
                :x(in_x), y(in_y), direction(in_direction), parent(in_parent)  {}
            int x, y;
            maze::Direction direction;
            std::shared_ptr<SJunction> parent;
            bool operator < (const SJunction &rhs) const {
                return std::tie(x, y, direction) < std::tie(rhs.x, rhs.y, rhs.direction);
            }
        };

        std::shared_ptr<SJunction> make_sharedJunction(int x, int y, maze::Direction direction, std::shared_ptr<SJunction> in_parent);
        std::shared_ptr<SJunction> make_sharedJunction(const SJunction &in_other);
        std::shared_ptr<SJunction> _lastJunctionTaken;
        std::stack<SJunction> _turnsToBeTaken;
        //std::set<SJunction> _turnsToBeTaken;
        std::set <SJunction> _turnsAlreadyTaken;
        void SJunctionDeleter(SJunction *);
    };
}
```

cpp:

```
#include "MazePlayerAIController.h"
#include "MazePlayerModel.h"
#include "MazeGameWorldModel.h"
#include "mathUtils.h"
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


namespace amazeinggame
{


    CMazePlayerAIController::CMazePlayerAIController(const CMazeGameWorldModel & in_worldModel)
    {
        _worldModel = &in_worldModel;
        _finishPoint = _worldModel->getFinishPoint();
        unsigned int seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        randomEngine = std::default_random_engine(seed);
    }


    CMazePlayerAIController::~CMazePlayerAIController()
    {
        //make sure _turnsAlreadTaken is present during the emptying of _turnsToBeTaken and nullifying _lastJunctionTaken - since it will add them there...
        while (!_turnsToBeTaken.empty())
            _turnsToBeTaken.pop();
        _lastJunctionTaken = nullptr;
    }


    void CMazePlayerAIController::update(CMazePlayerModel * const in_playerModel)
    {
        if ( !_worldModel)
            return; //init was not called, can't do anything...
        if (_worldModel->isMazeGameWon())
        {
            in_playerModel->stop();
            return; //if game was already won, we should stop caring...
        }
        auto playerState = in_playerModel->getPlayerState();
        int x = std::round(playerState.x), y = std::round(playerState.y);
        if (playerState.speedX != 0 || playerState.speedY != 0)
        {
            //check if we're still inside the previous room
            if (x == _prevX && y == _prevY)
                return;
        }
        //if (maze::getDirectionFromVector(playerState.speedX, playerState.speedY) != _prevDirection && (playerState.speedX != 0 || playerState.speedY != 0))
        //{
        //  //std::cerr << playerState.x << "," << playerState.y << ": Current walking direction is " 
        //      //<< maze::getDirectionFromVector(playerState.speedX, playerState.speedY)
        //      //<< " But AI thinks it\'s " << _prevDirection << std::endl;
        //  _prevDirection = maze::getDirectionFromVector(playerState.speedX, playerState.speedY);
        //}
        _prevX = x; _prevY = y;
        auto nextDir = getNextDirection(x, y, _prevDirection); //remember to remove the _prevDirection here, it's unncessary
        if (nextDir == maze::Direction::NotSet)
        { //means theres a bug somewhere...
            //std::cerr << "Could not figure out where to go from " << x << "," << y << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        if (nextDir != _prevDirection)
        {
            in_playerModel->stop();
            in_playerModel->setDirection(nextDir);
            //std::cerr << "Go " << nextDir << " on " << x << "," << y << std::endl;
            _prevDirection = nextDir;
        }
        /*else 
            std::cerr << "Continue " << _prevDirection << " on " << x << "," << y << std::endl;*/
    }


    bool CMazePlayerAIController::getPossibleTurns(std::array<maze::Direction,4> &out_possibleTurns, int & out_numOfPossibleTurns, int & out_preferedDirectionIdx, 
        maze::Direction & out_backDirection, int x, int y, maze::Direction in_direction, int depth)
    {
        auto possibleDirections = _worldModel->getMaze().getAllPossibleDirectionsFromPosition(x, y);
        auto prevDirectionVector = maze::getVectorFromDirection(in_direction);

        out_backDirection = maze::getDirectionFromVector(-prevDirectionVector.first, -prevDirectionVector.second);
        out_numOfPossibleTurns = 0;
        out_preferedDirectionIdx = -1; //if we can continue in the same directio, this would be preferable - keep this for later use. 
        for (const auto & direction : possibleDirections)
        {
            if (direction != out_backDirection && _turnsAlreadyTaken.find(SJunction{ x, y, direction }) == std::end(_turnsAlreadyTaken))
            {
                auto directionVector = maze::getVectorFromDirection(direction);
                if (x + directionVector.first == _finishPoint.first && y + directionVector.second == _finishPoint.second)
                {
                    out_preferedDirectionIdx = out_numOfPossibleTurns; //we win!!!
                    out_possibleTurns[out_numOfPossibleTurns++] = direction;
                    return true;
                }
                if (depth == 0)
                {
                    out_possibleTurns[out_numOfPossibleTurns++] = direction;
                }
                else
                {
                    //just look at the adjacent room.
                    //auto nextPossibleDirections = _worldModel->getMaze().getAllPossibleDirectionsFromPosition(x + directionVector.first, y + directionVector.second);
                    int numOfPossibleTurns, preferableDirectionIdx;
                    std::array<maze::Direction, 4> possibleTurns;
                    maze::Direction backDirection;
                    if (getPossibleTurns(possibleTurns, numOfPossibleTurns, preferableDirectionIdx, backDirection, 
                        x + directionVector.first, y + directionVector.second, direction, depth - 1))
                    {
                        out_preferedDirectionIdx = out_numOfPossibleTurns; //we win!!!
                        out_possibleTurns[out_numOfPossibleTurns++] = direction;
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (numOfPossibleTurns > 0)
                    {   //this is a possible direction to take.
                        if (direction == in_direction)
                            out_preferedDirectionIdx = out_numOfPossibleTurns;
                        out_possibleTurns[out_numOfPossibleTurns++] = direction;
                    }
                }


            }
            /*if (_turnsAlreadyTaken.find(SJunction{ x, y, direction }) != std::end(_turnsAlreadyTaken))
                std::cerr << "<*>Ignore possible turn to " << direction << " on " << x << "," << y << std::endl;*/
        }
        return false;
    }

    maze::Direction CMazePlayerAIController::getNextDirection(int x, int y, maze::Direction in_direction)
    {
        //check if the new room has a junction in it

        int numOfPossibleTurns, preferableDirectionIdx;
        std::array<maze::Direction, 4> possibleTurns;
        maze::Direction backDirection;
        if (getPossibleTurns(possibleTurns, numOfPossibleTurns, preferableDirectionIdx, backDirection, x, y, in_direction, _lookAheadDepth))
            return possibleTurns[preferableDirectionIdx]; //this means we know where the target is, no need to mock about.
        if (!isAlreadyWalking) //if this is the first time we walk - ignore one possible turn (we would get back to it eventually)
        {
            --numOfPossibleTurns;
            isAlreadyWalking = true;
        }
        if (preferableDirectionIdx >= 0)
        {
            if (numOfPossibleTurns == 1) //no need to do anything yet, we're doing fine!
                return in_direction;
            if (_currentWalkState == AIWalkState::Explore)
            { //only during exploration do we care about the current direction.
                //prefer to keep the same direction.

                //insert the rest of the turns to turnsToBeTaken if they are legal
                for (int i = 0; i < numOfPossibleTurns; ++i)
                {
                    if (i != preferableDirectionIdx)
                    {
                        _turnsToBeTaken.emplace( x, y, possibleTurns[i], _lastJunctionTaken );
                        //std::cerr << "<*>Remember to go back to take " << possibleTurns[i] << " on " << x << "," << y << std::endl;
                    }
                }
                _lastJunctionTaken = make_sharedJunction(x, y, in_direction, _lastJunctionTaken);
                //std::cerr << "<*>Last junction seen was on " << x << "," << y << " - continued going " << in_direction << std::endl;
                return in_direction;
            }
        }
        //now it's time to decide where to go!

        if (numOfPossibleTurns == 0) //this means there were no good turns to take - turn around, and go back to the last junction.
        { //this should not happen in rollback mode.
            if (_currentWalkState == AIWalkState::Rollback)
                //std::cerr << "Got lost during rollback..." << std::endl;
            if (_turnsToBeTaken.size()) //if there is where to roll back to, rollback.
            {
                _currentWalkState = AIWalkState::Rollback;
                if (_lastJunctionTaken)
                {
                    //std::cerr << "<*>Add turn to " << _lastJunctionTaken->direction << " on " << _lastJunctionTaken->x << "," << _lastJunctionTaken->y << " to forbiden turns" << std::endl;
                    _lastJunctionTaken = nullptr;
                }
                else
                    _currentWalkState = AIWalkState::Explore; //we get here only if rollback failed.
            }
            return backDirection;
        }
        if (numOfPossibleTurns == 1) //if there was just one possible direction to take - take it.
        {
            return possibleTurns[0];
        }
        if (_currentWalkState == AIWalkState::Explore) //now we have no obvious choice for new direction
        {
            iota(std::begin(_possibleTurnIdx), std::begin(_possibleTurnIdx) + numOfPossibleTurns, 0);
            std::shuffle(std::begin(_possibleTurnIdx), std::begin(_possibleTurnIdx) + numOfPossibleTurns, randomEngine);
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfPossibleTurns - 1; ++i) //first check in the waiting list
            {
                _turnsToBeTaken.emplace( x, y, possibleTurns[_possibleTurnIdx[i]], _lastJunctionTaken );
                //std::cerr << "<*>Remember to go back to take " << possibleTurns[_possibleTurnIdx[i]] << " on " << x << "," << y << std::endl;
            }
            _lastJunctionTaken = make_sharedJunction( x, y, possibleTurns[_possibleTurnIdx[numOfPossibleTurns - 1]], _lastJunctionTaken );
            //std::cerr << "<*>Last junction seen was on " << x << "," << y << " - taken " << _lastJunctionTaken->direction << std::endl;
            return possibleTurns[_possibleTurnIdx[numOfPossibleTurns - 1]];
        }
        else
        {
            //if (_turnsToBeTaken.top().x != x || _turnsToBeTaken.top().y != y)
            //  std::cerr << "<<!>*<<!>>>Wanted to go back to " << _turnsToBeTaken.top().x << "," << _turnsToBeTaken.top().y <<
            //  " but wound up in " << x << "," << y << std::endl;
            //else
            //  std::cerr << "Successfuly rolled back to take " << _turnsToBeTaken.top().direction << " in "
            //  << _turnsToBeTaken.top().x << "," << _turnsToBeTaken.top().y << std::endl;
            auto turnToTake = _turnsToBeTaken.top().direction;
            _lastJunctionTaken = make_sharedJunction(_turnsToBeTaken.top());
            //std::cerr << "<*>Last junction seen was on " << x << "," << y << " - taken " << _lastJunctionTaken->direction << std::endl;
            _turnsToBeTaken.pop();
            _currentWalkState = AIWalkState::Explore;
            return turnToTake;
        }

        return maze::Direction::NotSet; //this should never happen...
    }

    std::shared_ptr<CMazePlayerAIController::SJunction> CMazePlayerAIController::make_sharedJunction(int x, int y, maze::Direction direction, std::shared_ptr<SJunction> in_parent)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<SJunction>(new SJunction{ x, y, direction, in_parent }, 
            std::bind(&amazeinggame::CMazePlayerAIController::SJunctionDeleter, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
    std::shared_ptr<CMazePlayerAIController::SJunction> CMazePlayerAIController::make_sharedJunction(const SJunction &in_other)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<SJunction>(new SJunction(in_other), 
            std::bind(&amazeinggame::CMazePlayerAIController::SJunctionDeleter, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void CMazePlayerAIController::SJunctionDeleter(SJunction * junctionToDelete)
    {
        junctionToDelete->parent = nullptr; 
        _turnsAlreadyTaken.emplace(*junctionToDelete); 
        //std::cerr << "adding junction " << junctionToDelete->x << "," << junctionToDelete->y 
        //  << "-" << junctionToDelete->direction << " to black list" << std::endl; 
        delete junctionToDelete;
    }
}
```